# How to get to meta?

Tags: support, user-interface, meta

There's a [new toolbar](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/?cb=1) for all the SE sites. (That big black thing up there!)

Mostly I think it's pretty awesome.

> But how do I get to meta now?

Comment: It seems that the toolbar only facilitates movement across SE sites now, and has made in-site navigation more cumbersome (meta back to MO takes two clicks, instead of one) and has also slowed down my browser.

Comment: yes major chg, it would be nice if stackexchange mgt described this change somewhere/rationale.. aha found it. [se blog on new toolbar bkg](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/)

Comment: @vzn, I linked to the blog post right in my original post. Also, please don't use "texting abbreviations" here: it's a professional forum.

Comment: More generally, see [Where has the link to <X> gone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/) at the Mother Meta.

Comment: See this meta SE post: [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/228808).

Answer (score 17):

Just click on the Blue Stack Exchange sign, and there's a link to meta there.

Update:  This no longer works, and now one must click on the "word bubble  symbol" at the extreme right of the toolbar to get to meta.

Comment: The answer also tells you how to get back from meta to the main site!

Comment: The "October surprise" change is a bit confusing at first.  But the menu formerly found on the left (under the StackExchange sign) is now moved to the right.  Also from the change: It will be convenient to have a search field for the current site right there at the top, I think.

Answer (score 3):

On many pages there is a "community bulletin" box on the right side. It includes the word "meta" next to any meta posts listed there, and clicking on that takes you straight to the meta front page.

Alternatively, with an extra click you can select "help" in the toolbar and then "meta".

Comment: I hate the new toolbar.  How do you get from meta to the main site?

Comment: @BillJohnson - need to click on the StackExchange link at top left, then click on MathOverflow in the drop down list.

Comment: David means to click on the downward pointing arrow.  You then get a drop down list containing 10,000 or so links and can scroll down to find MO.

Comment: @BillJohnson: When I click on that MO and MOmeta show up right at the top.

Comment: Oh, I see that now.  Thanks, Scott & Lucia.

Comment: @BillJohnson, paraphrasing/misquoting the immortal Anton: "It'll be good when the SE folks start making arbitrary changes to our user interface again; everyone gets complacent and unnecessarily attached to the status quo."

Comment: I also like how my name in the toolbar has been replaced by a beautiful abstract design (which I think was chosen rather randomly when I first registered on MO).