# Where is the link to Meta from Mathoverflow?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, meta

When I go to mathoverflow.net, I don't see any indication on the page about how to get to MathOverflow Meta.  (I *think* it is supposed to be accessible from the "StackExchange" pulldown on the left of the top bar, but there is nothing there now except a link to the main StackExchange site.)

Possibly related: I don't see any links to chatrooms on the main Mathoverflow page.  (I do see such links on the MathOverflow Meta page though.)

Comment: See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1234/how-to-get-to-meta/1236#1236

Comment: Related to second part of the question (the "possibly unrelated" part): [Chatroom links disappeared](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3611).

Comment: The "StackExchange pulldown" is now on the right of the top bar, after a site redesign. (Confusingly, the original icon on the left is still there, but now does something different, as you observed.)

Comment: Well, the chat link on the right is back now.

Answer (score 1):

It's cleverly hidden under the Stack Exchange logo drop-down on the right-hand side of the top bar (NOT the one on the left-hand side of the top bar):

[image: image of the location described above]

Alternately, you can just type "meta." in the title bar after placing the cursor in front of the normal site's URL; in some cases this can be faster.